# Navigation Bar in Interface Builder Back Button Issues

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4, navigation, back-button

I'm not sure what's happening with my Navigation Controller.  I have a window with a Tab Bar Controller and 3 Navigation Controllers, they work fine when switching between the views they're set to.

However one View Controller has a Button in the View that pushes another View Controller onto the Navigation Controller, only the back button doesn't come up. I've made a screen that pops a copy of itself to the View Stack and when there are 3 or more Views on the stack, the back button shows up, until it gets to that second view again, and it disappears.  Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: As soon as you push a view into the navigation stack, the `back ` button shows up by default.

Comment: I got it, my Navigation Item inside that View Controller didn't have a name.  The back button defaults to the name of the Navigation Bar item of the previous view the first time.  If it's empty the button just won't show up.  That is horrible.